# Каких знаний в C# достаточно для написания UI автотестов для игр на Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, test-automation, unity3d-ui

За ранее извиняюсь, если данный вопрос был задан ранее, я только начинаю свой путь в данном ресурсе. Я мануальщик QA в геймдеве, проект под мобилки и так же есть ПК билд. Задумался об автотестировании, выбрал язык C#, выбрал фреймворк, но вот пока что не понятно, каких знаний по C# будет достаточно? Как понять, что дальше особо можно не изучать язык и для UI автоматизации, где в основном мы тупо ищем объекты на сцене и кликаем на них, данных знаний будет достаточно?

Comment: Ну и собстна как понять какие знания будут нужны? На ютубе очень мало инфы по автоматизации в геймдеве

Comment: Если вам надо дополнить вопрос, не пишите это в комментариях, просто нажмите кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь о unity, то язык ты по сути не выбирал, он там один. Программисты это не те, кто пишут код на языке программирования. Например HearthStone был сделан с помощью инструментов визуального программирования без кода, но занимались этим все равно программисты, язык лишь часть профессии, обязательная для владения, но не обязательная для применения. Язык это инструмент для строительства, а программисту нужно еще заниматься архитектурой и видом.

Тесты пишутся на языке и это язык нужно знать, синтаксис, уметь на нем писать и читать, вся матчасть, нет таких линий где можно остановиться, есть только отдельные возможности конкретных языков в которых нет нужды для конкретных задач, как например многопоточность. Всевозможные курсаы на ютубах вообщем то состоят только из матчасти и то без практики они бесполезны, нужно руку набивать что-то делая самостоятельно (не тесты).

Comment: Ну вообще, можно хоть на ассемблере писать, если фреймворк для автотестов поддерживает этот язык и тут уже не имеет разницы на чём работает сам движок)) а в целом - понял вас) спс за ответ)